# What is the "Menu Bar Mode"

Tags: starcraft-2

There is a part of the options menu where it asks if you want items in the Menu Bar to be visible and or clickable.

What is this menu bar mode? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the top bar in-game, where it says

> Menu (F10) | Achievements (F11) | Help (F12)

If you are familiar with the game, I'd suggest you hide it, so you can focus on the action and not having misclicks.